# When save as PDF, the password protected PDF saved as unprotected document

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, pdf, encryption

I am serving encrypted PDFs to a browser. When a user chooses "save as PDF" in Chrome on the print dialog, the file is being saved successfully, but it is no longer password protected. I want to end user to be able to print the document, but I don't want the end user to be able to remove the password protection.

[image: Screen shot taken from chrome browser]

Comment: This is not an iText question. The behavior you experience is caused by the viewer that allows a user to print a document as an insecure PDF. I will remove all references to iText from your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do. Saving as PDF in Chrome or printing to another PDF printer will create another similar PDF file but without encryption. Also the annotations and form fields will be flattened as page content.

Comment: I should admit that this answer helped me solve another problem. Thanks.